# How to get uninstalled apk information from sd card folder in android

Tags: java, android, listview

i want to get uninstalled apk file information with label name and icon from sd card/folder to display in a listview.

for that i am trying

```
     for (int i = 0; i < FilesInFolder.size(); i++)
     {

           PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

           String dir = "mnt/sdcard/" + FilesInFolder.get(i);
           PackageInfo pi=pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(dir,0);
           System.err.println("files were " + pi);
           pi.applicationInfo.sourceDir = dir;
           pi.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = dir;
           Drawable APKicon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
           String AppName = (String)pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm);

       }
```

FilesInFolder is a `ArrayList<String>` where it has all the file names stored in sd card folder. I am able to get all files correctly from sd card folder but i am getting `PackageInfo pi` value as null for all files

Here is my logcat

```
  10-29 00:55:14.832: W/PackageParser(17057): Skipping dir: mnt/sdcard/tudou.apk
  10-29 00:55:14.832: W/System.err(17057): files were null
  10-29 00:55:14.833: W/PackageParser(17057): Skipping dir:       mnt/sdcard/com.nexbits.video-1.apk
  10-29 00:55:14.833: W/System.err(17057): files were null
  10-29 00:55:14.834: W/PackageParser(17057): Skipping dir: mnt/sdcard/com.myapp.locksettings-2.apk
  10-29 00:55:14.834: W/System.err(17057): files were null
```

Can any anyone get me where i stuck up at?

Comment: What is there in logcat for :   System.err.println("files were " + pi);

Comment: files were null @Prince